# Convert iso timestamp to date format with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timestamp, iso

This seems like a pretty simple question but I can't seem to get an answer for it. How can I convert an iso timestamp to display the date/time using JavaScript?

Example timestamp: 2012-04-15T18:06:08-07:00

Any help is appreciated, Google is failing me. Thank you.

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Comment: A unix timestamp and iso timestamp are not the same, so no, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Is your ISO timestamp you have a string? and you want to parse it into a javascript `Date()` class?

Comment: jfriend00, I put an example timestamp up there 2012-04-15T18:06:08-07:00. That's exactly what I what I want to do, I just want to take that timestamp, run it through javascript and have it return in date format Something like "Jan 1, 2010 12:00:21" (that timestamp wouldn't actually convert to that). However I have been unable to figure out how to do this with an iso timestamp. I know how to do this in PHP but I want to do it in JavaScript so it will be relative to the user's timezone.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Pass it to the Date constructor.

```
> var date = new Date('2012-04-15T18:06:08-07:00')
> date
  Mon Apr 16 2012 04:06:08 GMT+0300 (EEST)
```

For more information about Date, check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date.

Comment: Well that was significantly easier than I thought it was... thanks

Comment: This does not appear to work in any version of IE before IE9 or versions of Firefox before Firefox 4.

Comment: Indeed, parsing ISO dates is part of supporting EcmaScript 5. If you need to work with older browsers you're better off using something like the code below.

Answer (score 4):

The newest version of javascript (v1.85 or higher in some of the latest browsers) can handle the ISO dates directly so you can just pass your string directly to the `Date()` constructor like this:

```
var jsDate = new Date("2012-04-15T18:06:08-07:00");
```

But older browsers (any version of IE before IE9, any version of Firefox before 4, etc...) do not support this.  For those browsers, you can either get a library that can do this for you like [datejs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/) or parse it yourself like this:

```
var t = "2012-04-15T18:06:08-07:00";

function convertDate(t) {
    var dateRE = /(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)T(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)([+\-]\d+):(\d+)/;
    var match = t.match(dateRE);
    var nums = [], item, date;
    if (match) {
        for (var i = 1; i < match.length; i++) {
            nums.push(parseInt(match[i], 10));
        }
        if (nums[7] < 0) {
            nums[8] *= -1;
        }
        return(new Date(nums[0], nums[1] - 1, nums[2], nums[3] - nums[6], nums[4] - nums[7], nums[5]));
    }
}

var jsDate = convertDate(t);
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/QSgn6/

Answer (score 1):

```js
const now = new Date(); // create a new date object with the current time

// Here are some examples of what javascript provides:
console.log({
    now,
    toDateString: now.toDateString(),
    toISOString: now.toISOString(),
    toLocaleString: now.toLocaleString(),
    toLocaleDateString: now.toLocaleDateString(),
    toLocaleTimeString: now.toLocaleTimeString(),
    toUTCString: now.toUTCString(),
    toTimeString: now.toTimeString(),
})
```

This prints:

```js
[LOG]: {
  "now": "2022-08-02T10:29:26.891Z",
  "toDateString": "Tue Aug 02 2022",
  "toISOString": "2022-08-02T10:29:26.891Z",
  "toLocaleString": "02/08/2022, 11:29:26",
  "toLocaleDateString": "02/08/2022",
  "toLocaleTimeString": "11:29:26",
  "toUTCString": "Tue, 02 Aug 2022 10:29:26 GMT",
  "toTimeString": "11:29:26 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)"
}
```

Alternatively, for more options, you can use something like [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/). For example, I used it here to get a date into a UK readable date string:

```js
import moment from "moment";

const now = new Date(); // create a new date object with the current time

const getTimeFormatted = (date: number) =>
  moment(date).format("DD/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");

console.log(getTimeFormatted(now)) // prints: 01/08/2022 11:29 am
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I've seen so far that is able to use the client's desktop timezone and changes real-time with the timezone setting:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Use: timeZoneConvert("2015-11-03T17:36:20.970");
    //Mon Nov 02 2015 17:36:20 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)  [Date object]

    //To format string use: timeZoneConvertFormatted("2015-11-03T17:36:20.970")
    //November 2, 2015 5:36 PM

    //Works even when I change client timezone to Pacific Standard
    //Mon Nov 02 2015 15:36:20 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)



var months = ["", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
function timeZoneConvert(dateStr) {
    var d = parse_iso8601(dateStr);
    //Change (- 360) constant for your server, mine is Central Standard
    var dTimezoneOffset = new Date(d.getTime() - ((new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() - 360)*60000);
    return dTimezoneOffset;
}   

function timeZoneConvertFormatted(dateStr) {
    return fDateTime(timeZoneConvert(dateStr));
}   


function fDateTime(date1) {
    var date = date1.getDate();
    var year = date1.getFullYear();
    var month = months[date1.getMonth() + 1];
    var h = date1.getHours();
    var m = date1.getMinutes();
    var ampm = "AM";
    if(m < 10) {
        m = "0" + m;
    }
    if(h > 12) {
        h = h - 12;
        var ampm = "PM";
    }
    return month + " " + date + ", " + year + " " + h + ":" + m + " " + ampm;
}



    var iso8601extended = /^\d{4}(-\d{2}(-\d{2}([T ]\d{2}(:\d{2}(:\d{2})?)?([,.]\d+)?(Z|[+-]\d{2}(:\d{2})?)?)?)?)?$/;
    var iso8601basic = new RegExp(iso8601extended.source.replace(/[:-]\\d/g, '\\d'));
    var firstNumber = /[^\d]*(\d+)/g;
    function parse_iso8601(s) {
        s = s.replace(/,/g, '.');
        var matches = iso8601extended.exec(s);
        if (matches) {
            s = s.substr(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '') + s.substr(10).replace(/:/g, '');
        }
        matches = iso8601basic.exec(s);
        if (!matches) {
            return null;
        }
        var d = new Date();
        d.setUTCFullYear(toNumber(matches[0].substring(0, 4)));
        d.setUTCMonth(matches[1] ? toNumber(matches[1].substr(0, 2)) - 1 : 0);
        d.setUTCDate(matches[2] ? toNumber(matches[2].substr(0, 2)) : 1);
        var hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0, milliseconds = 0;
        var fraction = matches[6] ? parseFloat(matches[6]) : 0;
        if (matches[3]) {
            hours = toNumber(matches[3].substr(1, 2));
            if (matches[4]) {
                minutes = toNumber(matches[4].substr(0, 2));
                if (matches[5]) {
                    seconds = toNumber(matches[5].substr(0, 2));
                    milliseconds = 1000 * fraction;
                } else {
                    seconds = 60 * fraction;
                }
            } else {
                minutes = 60 * fraction;
            }
        }
        if (!matches[7]) {
            d.setHours(hours);
            d.setMinutes(minutes);
        } else {
            d.setUTCHours(hours);
            d.setUTCMinutes(minutes);
        }
        d.setUTCSeconds(seconds);
        d.setUTCMilliseconds(milliseconds);
        if (matches[7] && matches[7] != 'Z') {
            offset = toNumber(matches[7].substr(1, 2)) * 60;
            if (matches[8]) {
                 offset += toNumber(matches[8].substr(0, 2));
            }
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + 60000 * offset * (matches[7].substr(0, 1) == '-' ? 1 : -1));
        }
        return d;
    }
    function toNumber(s) {
        return parseInt(s.replace(/^0+(\d)/, '$1'));
    }
</script>
```