# How to compare time in MongoDB with different time stamp and format?

Tags: mongodb, date

I have the dataset looks as following, the time is record in timezone GMT:

```
{"id":1,"Timestamp:"Mon, 11 May 2015 07:57:46 GMT"}
{"id":2,"Timestamp:"Mon, 11 May 2015 08:57:46 GMT"}
```

I would like to count how many rows for a certain time period:

```
from ISODate("2015-05-10T01:40:08.963Z")
to ISODate("2015-05-12T01:40:08.963Z")
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Do you have your timestamp stored as strings? Like in first example?

Comment: @SalvadorDali yes, it is stored as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no normal way of doing it. It is better to convert your database to a normal format and the faster you will do it to better.

What I would do is to use [foreach for every document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) and modify it with the following [javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10181798/1090562).

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution to your challenge. Both Data formats (GMT and ISO FORMAT) can be passed easily.

Just follow the function below:
function findRows (){

```
//Convert the dates to strings
const isoDateInUTC1 = new Date("2015-05-12T01:40:08.963Z").getTime(),
isoDateInUTC2 = new Date("2015-05-12T01:40:08.963Z").getTime(),
rows= await collection.find({}).lean();

Let rowCount = 0;

for (let count = 0; count < trades.length; count++) {
   var gmtDateUTC = new Date("").getTime(rows[count].Timestamp);
    isoDateInUTC1 < gmtDateUTC < isoDateInUTC2  
    ?  rowCount++;
 }
return rowCount; 
}
```

I think this should work, although you should still be able to take the `isoDateInUTC1` and `isoDateInUTC2` as parameters so you can reuse the function. More so, You should be able to run a similar code in the mongodb query but this should still do the job.