# Displaying a date object on the page in a readable format

Tags: javascript, date, object, time

I have a form that the user is filling out that includes a date that the user can set. At the moment the date objects are in the following format

`"2021-07-29T00:16:20.391Z"`

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181649/convert-iso-timestamp-to-date-format-with-javascript) I was able to convert it with the `new Date()` constructor

`let readable = new Date(date)`

At this point the date is `Sun Aug 01 2021 17:16:20 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)` I can see it in the browser console.

This format is what I want, however it is an object so I cannot display it on the page like I need to. So I use `JSON.Stringify()`.

`let stringTime = JSON.stringify(readable)`

This allows the time to be shown on the page, however it reverts to the original format of `"2021-07-29T00:16:20.391Z"` I can't seem to get the `readable` Object to display on the page without reverting to the hard to read date format.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `let stringTime = new Date().toString();`